# How to do two count queries in one?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE followers (
  user_id int not null REFERENCES users(id) on DELETE CASCADE,
  following int not null REFERENCES users(id) on DELETE CASCADE,
  PRIMARY key (user_id, following)
);
```

From this I want to fetch both followers and following counts. Currently I am doing it like this:

```
-- user 1 following
SELECT count(*) from followers f
WHERE f.user_id = 1;

-- user 1 followers
SELECT count(*) from followers f
WHERE f.following = 1;
```

Is there any way to do this as a single query?

Desired output:

```
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| followers | following |
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| 2         | 1         |
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag.  Postgres supports inline constraints; I don't think MySQL does.  Tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: MySQL accepts the inline syntax but silently ignores it

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it is not simpler.  In Postgres, you can use a lateral join:

```
SELECT user_id, sum(is_followed), sum(is_following)
FROM followers f CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES (user_id, 1, 0, following),
             (following, 0, 1, user_id)
     ) v(user_id, is_followed, is_following, other_id)
WHERE other_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [FILTER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) in the COUNT():

```
SELECT  
        COUNT(*)    FILTER(WHERE user_id = 1)   AS followers
    ,   COUNT(*)    FILTER(WHERE following = 1) AS following
FROM    followers
WHERE   user_id = 1
OR      following = 1;
```

Comment: Alternatively: `where 1 in (user_id, following)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I totally agree! I thought about it but didn't use it on purpose to keep it as simple as possible. For many people the IN() construction is unknown and creates fear... But again, I would definitely go for the IN() construction for my production code